# obstacles in rviz

Tags: navigation, rviz, nxt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using a NXT with lejos I want move_base to publish on /move_base/local_costmap/obstacles so that I can see the obstacles in rviz.
But at the moment it doesn't work.
How should I set the costmaps configuration files?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47136/obstacles-in-rviz/) by [camilla](https://answers.ros.org/users/2828/camilla/) on ROS Answers with karma: 255 on 2012-10-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can find information about the setup of move_base here:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup#Robot_Setup

and documentation about costmaps here:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/costmap_2d

---

Originally posted by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) with karma: 2108 on 2012-10-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3